# Access variables in a struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a small vector engine and I'm having some trouble accessing the variables I have made in my `struct`.

Here's my `struct`:

```
struct vectorVariables {

    float v = 0, a = 0;
    float u = 20;
    float deltaT = 0.01;
    float posNew = 0 , posOld = 0;
    float gravity = -9.81;
};
```

All I want to be able to do for example, is print out one of these variables to the console.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown, so the problem must be in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: So where's the problem? What have you tried doing?

Comment: What kind of trouble? Compiler errors, unexpected results? Have you read a good C++ book? If not, you definitely should. If you have trouble with existing code, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] as well as a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables are available if you create an object. With that declaration in scope, and with the appropriate headers included, try this:

```
int main() {
    vectorVariables vv;
    std::cout << vv.v << " " << vv.a << "\n";
}
```